# Search box results for tags in tumblr

Tags: html, css

I have recently added a search box to my tumblr blog which looks like **[this](http://funnyadults.tumblr.com)**, but when I enter a 'tag' into the search box and press enter/search button, it show nothing in the search result page. I think I have the wrong html code for this. Please help me to write the correct html code for this search box.

CSS :

```css
#search1{
    top:185px;
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 68%;
    width: 300px;
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index:3;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
  }
.container-4{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container-4 input#search{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #40c143;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.container-4 input#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #fff;
}
 
.container-4 input#search:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #fff;  
}
 
.container-4 input#search::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #fff;  
}
 
.container-4 input#search:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #fff;  
}

.container-4 button.icon{
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #4f5b66;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 10pt;
 
  -webkit-transition: all .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .55s ease;
  -o-transition: all .55s ease;
  transition: all .55s ease;
}

.container-4:hover button.icon, .container-4:active button.icon, .container-4:focus button.icon{
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
 
.container-4:hover button.icon:hover{
  background: white;
}
```

HTML :

```html
<div id="search1">
  <div class="container-4">
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to build this using specific tumblr tags, check here for reference: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#search If you want this in an answer with code, let me know.

Comment: @lharby well, actually i would like the 'search' work with the same search box which I put in the blog (link is given above). Can you please help me or write the html code. please.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well functionally the following code should work (but it's untested).

I have basically just amalgamated your code with the code from the tumblr docs.

The issue you are going to have is styling the button. As this markup is slightly different, but I as I say I have tried to amalgamate it.

```
<div id="search1">
  <div class="container-4">
    <form action="/search" method="get">
       <input type="text" id="search" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" placeholder="Search..."/>
       <button class="icon" type="submit">Search<i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have implemented it as you said on this blog  www.funny-adults.com . But I think there is some problem with the search results. For example : You can see 'POPULAR' tag in the nav menubar, when you click it, it's shows results as funny-adults.com/tagged/popular . and when i put "POPULAR" in the search box and hit enter, it shows other results that www.funny-adults.com/tagged/popular

Comment: This works: http://funnyadults.tumblr.com/search/abcd as you have posts tagged #abcd but you do not have any posts tagged popular. Search will only return tags also, body content is not indexed.

Comment: also /tagged/popular returns no results (this is the default if the page cannot be found)

Comment: and also on [this](http://funnyadults.tumblr.com) blog, i tagged 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 7th post with the tag #abcd , but when i search 'abcd', it shows only 3 posts : 2nd, 3rd and 7th post.

Comment: Well I think that is to do with infinite scroll not working. I am seeing errors in the console for your blog, you need to include jquery. I think though that that is a completely different question. If there is an option to disable infinite scrolling in your theme I would turn it off and retest. See here: http://i.imgur.com/0hUgCvE.png

Comment: yes, that's true that i have not defined the jquery for infinite scroll, since i didn't wanted my posts to be scrolled infinitely. I wanted it go page by page.  Will it not work without infinitescroll jquery ? If not, please tell me how to add the infinitescroll jquery.

Comment: I think you can disable infinite scroll in the theme options. Go to Edit Theme, and then it should be an option you can toggle in the left hand panel under 'Theme Options'.

Comment: and also there is one more problem to the search result. If I search **fun** in the search box, it shows results for all tags having "fun" word inside . for example : funny, fun fact, fun, wtf fun fact etc.